# Return HTML page with Spring Controller

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

So, apparently, I'm trying to return an HTML file with help of the Spring Controller.

I already have added Thymeleaf dependencies and also tried the following ways to configure it:

1.

```
@RequestMapping ("/")
@ResponseBody
public String homeDisplay() {
    return "homepage";
}
```

2. 

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping ("/")
public ModelAndView index () {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("homepage");
    return modelAndView;
}
}
```

Anyway, didn't help, I get Whitelabel Error Page.

**Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sun Dec 13 20:14:04 EET 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available**

How can I fix it and display the HTML I need.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: The question is - how to fix the problem and display the html file I need.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to provide as much relevant info as possible. There may be many issues in the project you have. Here at SO there is no magic. :-) In this case show your project structure. An image may be.! Also show your pom/gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running in to a similar problem when trying to get a homepage to show up for a REST API that I was making. The project does not have Thymeleaf though. I used the following and this worked for me. The following code makes the home.html file, stored in resources/static to show up when the application starts. It's a static page and no data is sent to it.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() throws Exception {
        return "home.html"; //note that this says .html
    }
}
```

For a project that I was using Thymeleaf in, I have the following code which shows the login page stored in resources/templates folder.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginForm() {
        return "login"; //note that this is just the name of the file with no extension
    }
}
```

Be sure to put the html file in the correct folder. My guess is that since you're using Thymeleaf, you will probably be using some templates.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `@RequestMapping` with `@GetMapping("/")` or `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Why? because @RequestMapping will map to any request to that URL, so you have to specify that it's a GET request (I suppose that is what you want to use).

Since you didn't share your frontend code that is sending the request we can't tell if there is a problem there. Please share it as well.